# How does FusionAuth compare to other auth providers?

Tags: fusionauth

We're checking out Auth Providers and was wondering how FusionAuth compares to the others?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of, FusionAuth is free. Developers can use it for any application and even deploy to production with any number of users. All of the features of FusionAuth are available for free as well.

FusionAuth provides all of the core features that an identity provider must provide. These include registration, login, SSO, MFA, password hashing, password constraints, password reset, email templates, OAuth, OpenID Connect and others. In addition to the core features, FusionAuth also provides localization features, reporting, analytics, user segmentation, user search and a user management UI.

FusionAuth is single-tenant and downloadable. You can download it to your dev box, deploy it on a bare-metal server, run it in any cloud or deploy it to Docker. This provides a lot flexibility and FusionAuth (the company) can host it for you in an AWS private cloud if you need.

Finally, FusionAuth is built to scale. You can spin up new instances of it to handle large login volumes (because password hashing is expensive). We've tested it with a few hundred million users and it performs nicely.

Here's a quick example of just one of the numerous of APIs that FusionAuth provides.

```
$ curl -H'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d'{"loginId":"test@fusionauth.io", "password":"password"}' \
       https://localhost:9011/api/login
```

This is the Login API and you can find the full documentation here: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login

Comment: It would be a nice touch to mention you're the CEO @brian-pontarelli ;)

Comment: Yeah. I probably should have mentioned that in my reply. Though, I hope my answer wasn’t too salesy or markety. It’s all quite accurate still, except now we have a few paid features, but they are awesome and well worth the money. Okay, that was a little salesy. 

Answer (score 1):

There are comparison docs to other common solutions like Auth0 here. 
https://fusionauth.io/blog/2018/10/19/auth0-and-fusionauth-a-tale-of-two-solutions

At the bottom are links to comparisons to Active Directory, Cognito, Firebase, Ping Identity, Okta, and OneLogin.

Comment: Using a company's blog is not a valid way of comparing them to other competitors. The information will be inherently biased.